# accessing array values without square brackets in php

Tags: php, arrays, square-bracket

In php how can I access an array's values without using square brackets around the key? My particular problem is that I want to access the elements of an array returned by a function. Say function(args) returns an array. Why is
    $var = function(args)[0];
yelling at me about the square brackets? Can I do something like
    $var = function(args).value(0);
or am I missing something very basic?

Comment: php refers to this as function array referencing.

It has been included in php since version 5.4

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the others have said, you pretty much have to use a temporary variable:

```
$temp = myFunction();
$value = $temp[0];
```

But, if know the structure of the array being returned it is possible to avoid the temporary variable.

If you just want the first member:

```
$value = reset(myFunction());
```

If you want the last member:

```
$value = end(myFunction());
```

If you want any one in between:

```
// second member
list(, $value) = myFunction();

// third
list(, , $value) = myFunction();

// or if you want more than one:

list(, , $thirdVar, , $fifth) = myFunction();
```

Comment: Hey, clever! `list()` never ceases to amaze me. +1.

Comment: reset() and end() require the arguments be references. You get an E_STRICT notice in recent versions of php.

Comment: yes, i have been doing this with temporary variables, but was wondering whether i really needed to. now i'm just wondering _why_ i have to. but in any case your list() usage is pretty clever. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, when getting an array as a function result, you unfortunately have to do an extra step:

```
$temp_array = function($args);
$var = $temp_array[0];
```

For objects, this has been relaxed in PHP 5. You can do:

```
$echo function($args)->property;
```

(provided `function` returns an object of course.)

Comment: It sucks but this is the only way to do this. One of the many reasons to hate PHP.

Comment: @Luke true, but not *that* bad imo. Who knows, it may get fixed in PHP 7 :)

Comment: @Luke - that's a bit strong isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getKey($array, $key){
    return $array[$key];
}

$var = getKey(myFunc(args), $key);
```

There is no way to do this without adding a user function unfortunately. It is just not part of the syntax.

You could always just do it the old fashion way

```
$array = myFunc();
$value = $array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly matches your expecting is:

```
echo pos(array_slice($a=myFunc(), pos(array_keys(array_keys($a), 'NameOfKey'));
```

answered Kinetix Kin, Taipei

Answer (score 1):

if you want this, its probably best to be returning an object (unfortunately, its totally lame php doesnt support this). Heres a crazy way i was able to figure out though, out of novelty (please dont do this!):

```
function returnsArray(){
    return array("foo" => "bar");
}

echo json_decode(json_encode((object)returnsArray()))->foo;
//prints 'bar'
```

So yeah..until they add support for array dereferencing in php, i think you should probably just cast the return array as an object:

```
return (object)array("foo" => "bar");
```

and then you can do returnsArray()->foo, since php relaxes dereferencing for objects but not arrays.. or of course write a wrapper function like others have suggested.

Comment: also, looks like support for this has been recently added to php? http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing